# put a div in center and align an image to its "left" side

Tags: html, css

[Here is the demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/rhzsc6g2/)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png"/>
     <span class="text">Title Here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to put the "Title" in center and then place the logo, next to it in the left side of it.

The title name would be dynamic so it should always be at the center irrespective of length

Comment: So you want text absolute in the middle but text+image not absolute in the middle?

Comment: I suggest you use clientWidth for the text, then marginLeft = calc( (100% - text_element.clientWidth)/2), then position:absolute for the image, and set left: to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4m91asgu/)

```
.container{
    padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;
    height: 247px;
    width: 780px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #2D343D;
}

.logo {
  width: 55px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.header {
        height: 56px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-size: 29.98px;
        letter-spacing: 0.43px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change CSS

```
.container{
    padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;
    height: 247px;
    width: 780px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #2D343D;
}

.logo {
  width: 55px;
  float:left;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.header {
        height: 56px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-top: 15px;
        font-size: 29.98px;
        letter-spacing: 0.43px;
        line-height: 40px;
        text-align:center;
        position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d902fzyn/

Comment: Logo is on the extreme left side of the screen. It should be adjacent to the title

Comment: remove padding-left for .container class

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you want it to be?

```css
.container {
  padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;
  height: 247px;
  width: 780px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background-color: #2D343D;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  width: 55px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.header {
  height: 56px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 29.98px;
  letter-spacing: 0.43px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png" />
    <span class="text">Title Here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You added both position to `.header` class (its written twice). Please verify the answer